Unable to list table names of a database using SQL statement and Python codes on Spyder console
on command line shell for sqlite3, when I entered .tables on the prompt and run the command, it would print out all the table names, eg. orders, project, tasks.
However, when I run the following sql statement and python code on Spyder console to list all the tables in my.db, it is not printing any table names. How could I change my code so that I would print out all the tables in my.db?
sql_statement = """SELECT name FROM sqlite_master  
  WHERE type='table';"""

import sqlite3
try:
    with sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/myname/Desktop/sqlite-python/my.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        conn.commit()
except sqlite3.OperationalError as error:
    print("Failed to create tables:",error)


execute returns a result object, which you're currently ignoring. You can use this result object to fetch the result's rows from the database, and then print them out. E.g.:
cursor = conn.cursor()
res = cursor.execute(sql_statement)
print("\n".join(res.fetchall()))

